# How to echo result of sed to a file in bash?

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, echo

I am trying to echo the result of a sed command to a different .html file.
The sed command is to read a .txt file line by line and take only the second value separated by a comma-delimiter.

Here is what I have:

```
ind=1
while [ $ind -lt 4 ]
do
     echo "<tr><td>" >> ${HTML_FILE}
     echo "`sed -n '$ind p' ${TEXT_FILE} | awk -F ',' '{print $2}'`" >> ${HTML_FILE}
     echo "</td></tr>" >> ${HTML_FILE}
     ind=$((ind+1))
done
```

The contents of ${TEXT_FILE}:

```
709A8, Text 1 | 34%
354Y7, Text 2 | 86%
F1065, Text 3 | 100%
```

When I ran my code, here's my output. For some reason it prints 'nd p':

```
<tr><td>
 nd p
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
 nd p
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
 nd p
</td></tr>
```

Expected output should be something like:

```
<tr><td>Text 1 | 34%</td></tr>
<tr><td>Text 2 | 86%</td></tr>
<tr><td>Text 3 | 100%</td></tr>
```

Comment: Don't use ```echo "`cmd`"``` just use `cmd` instead. in `sed -n '$ind p'` $ind does not get replaced by its content use `sed -n $ind' p'`

Comment: You still need to (or at least should) quote `$ind` with double quotes to prevent word-splitting and pathname expansion.

Comment: @chepner: Good point, I left the quotes away because this is one of the rare cases where it is save (`ind=1` and `ind=$((ind+1))`). But you are right it is good practice to just add the quotes anyway.

Comment: I recommend to use xmlstarlet to generate HTML/XML.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I am actually only starting to learn shell scripting. In fact I only learned how to use sed and awk today! Haha but thank you really, I will take note of everything you guys said. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or just awk:

```
awk -F, 'NR < 4 {print "<tr><td>" $2 "</td></tr>"}' "$TEXT_FILE" >> "$HTML_FILE"
```

Comment: This one.  Though I think even the `NR < 4` is redundant, since the OP didn't indicate what the ‘index less than 4’ test was for.

Comment: True, probably due the OP's looping over the indices, one needs prior knowledge of the size of the file.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed. I switched from `s///` to `s|||` and from regex to extended regexp (`-r`).

```
sed -r 's|^[^,]*, (.*)|<tr><td>\1</td></tr>|' file
```

Output:

```
<tr><td>Text 1 | 34%</td></tr>
<tr><td>Text 2 | 86%</td></tr>
<tr><td>Text 3 | 100%</td></tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

At the very least, abandon `sed` and `awk` altogether. Running them once for each line is overkill.

```
ind=1
while [ "$ind" -lt 4 ]
do
     IFS=, read _ x _
     echo "<tr><td>$x</td></tr>"
     ind=$((ind+1))
done < "$TEXT_FILE" >> "$HTML_FILE"
```

Comment: If this is bash, `for ((ind=1; ind < 4; ind++)); do ...`

Comment: Calling `read` once per line is also overkill. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice). Just [call awk once](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52316606/1745001).

Comment: For something this small, the overhead of `read` is negligible, and probably comparable to the overhead of starting a new process to run `awk`.

Comment: There's no reason to think the OPs real input file is small and when you have a choice between a tool that will run fast on small or large files vs a tool that will only run fast on small files (where fast execution doesn't matter) and there's no other benefits to the latter it just makes sense to use the former, especially when the former requires less code and is more robust.

Comment: @EdMorton It doesn't matter how big the input file is if they are only processing the first 4 lines. Maybe in real life, the upper bound on `ind` is 24000, not 4, in which case I would definitely recommend `awk`. But in the question as stated, there is no problem with just using the shell.

Comment: Exactly, maybe in real life, the upper bound on ind is 24000, not 4. The OP simply posted a [mcve] as required to demonstrate the problem, I don't think it's reasonable to assume based on that [mcve] that she's always dealing with 3-line input files and again, the awk solution is not only the right one for larger input files but it's more concise and more robust (yours will fail if the input contains `\t` for example and will behave differently with different `echo`s) than the shell loop so IMHO there's no question which one to use.